# Change views in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` with a `UIToolBar` at the top with 3 buttons and a `UIView`,  when touch upInside those buttons I have to change the views that the controller has. What can I do to get my porpuse? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use something like a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to control the view stack and then have your button(s) call one of these methods for the `Touch Up Inside` action:

- `pushViewController:animated:`
- `popViewControllerAnimated:`
- `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`
- `popToViewController:animated:`

Here is a good [uinavigationcontroller-tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/) to look into.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this for each of the actions you set up.

In the .h file of the current viewController:

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    OtherViewController *otherViewController;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet OtherViewController *otherViewController;
```

Then in the .m file of the current viewController you need to add the following for each IBAction (touch up inside).

At the top of the .m file add:

```
@synthesize otherViewController;
```

Then make an IBAction and put the following line of code to display the other view:

```
[self presentModalViewController:otherViewController animated:NO];
```

In your `otherViewController` you can dismiss itself by using:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

NOTE: The other thing you will need to do is create a UIViewController in Interface Builder for each of the views you plan to display. You need to then go into the identity inspector and set the Class as `OtherViewController`. You then need to link the IBOutlet to the `OtherViewController` as normal.

There is a [YouTube video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsj-ghv5tbA&feature=related) which covers all of what I have mentioned above. It's a nice simple way to get started.

Comment: thanks for the post, i think i should be a little more specific. i don't want to use any other uiviewcontroller. i just need one uiviewcontroller which has the toolbar with the three buttons inside it and an uiview below the toolbar, this uiview is gonna contain depending on which button was pressed a view. So, the uiview is gonna contain 3 different uiviews at different moments.

Comment: What i did is to create 3 different UIview which contain their own controls. then the uiviewcontroller with properties toolbar and viewcontainer. In the ViewdidLoad() method i created an uiviewxxxx and then maid viewcontroller = uiviewxxxx; then created an instance of the first view and made viewcontroller = firstview; to show it in the uiviewcontroller. what can i do on the button touchupinside method to switch between the 3 views? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`UiViewController` view property is the base view you are seeing. It could be set(replaced with another). SO replace the view object of `ViewController` with another view you created.

```
UIView * customView = [[[UIView alloc] initWIthFrame:viewFrame] autorelease];
[self setView:customView];
```

Here self represent the current `viewController`.